# Cannot redeclare class in my MVC

Tags: php

```
<?php

class OrdersModel
{

    public static function wishlistcreate($item, $user, $username){

        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        $btc = System::bitcoinconnect();

        //get the wishlist product, where username and still for sale 
        $wishlist = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN wishlist ON wishlist.wishlist_product=products.id WHERE wishlist_username=? AND products.enddate > NOW() AND products.quantity > 0 AND products.enabled=1");
        $wishlist->execute(array($user));
        $product = $wishlist->fetch();

        if($product):

            $get_user_information = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
            $get_user_information->execute(array($user));
            $user_result = $get_user_information->fetch();

            $createorder = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(orders_username,orders_amount,orders_product,orders_firstname, orders_lastname, orders_address1, orders_address2, orders_zipcode, orders_city, orders_country, orders_btcaddress, orders_status,orders_wishlist, orders_wishlist_user) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            //get btc address, check it's valid, then if isset run query below
            $createorder->execute(array($username->username, $product->price + $product->shippingcost, $product->wishlist_product, $user_result->firstname, $user_result->lastname, $user_result->address1, $user_result->address2, $user_result->zipcode, $user_result->city, $user_result->country, $btc->getnewaddress(), 0, 1, $user,));

        else:
        echo 'nahhh'; //dbg
            //error, item has ended or item not in users watch list.
        endif;
    }
```

I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Bitcoin

Which is a class in a another file, here's is my $btc function:

```
public static function bitcoinconnect() {
    include Config::get('PATH_LIBS')."jsonRPCClient.php";
    //connect to bitcoin rpc use https ALWAYS!!
    $bitcoin = new Bitcoin("yadda");
    return $bitcoin;
}
```

I am using an mvc so each function counts as a page, but I have used

```
$btc = System::bitcoinconnect();
```

in another function/page, how can I go about only declaring the above code for all of that file so I don't get the cannot redeclare class.

Comment: do `include_once` instead of `include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function bitcoinconnect() {
include_once Config::get('PATH_LIBS')."jsonRPCClient.php";
//connect to bitcoin rpc use https ALWAYS!!
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin("yadda");
return $bitcoin;
}
```